# Fatal error: Non-abstract method...must contain body

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller, methods

I have an error concerning a function in one of my class

```
<?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/SITEBOUSILLE/models/utilisateur.php';

class formInscription {

private $user;    
public function __construct(){
    $this->user = new Utilisateur();
}

public function inscription($pseudo, $login, $password, $mail);{
    session_start();
    $row = $this->user->setUser($pseudo, $login, $password, $mail);
    header ("Location:  /SITEBOUSILLE ");
     }
 }
?>
```

My navigator is telling me this :

> Fatal error: Non-abstract method formInscription::inscription() must >contain body in C:\wamp\www\SITEBOUSILLE\controler\inscription\controleur_inscription_form.php on line 12

I don't really know why this error is appearing because I have nearly the exact same class (but for connexion) and it works perfectly...

Here is the code for the "utilisateur" class, just in case...

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/SITEBOUSILLE/models/model.php';

class Utilisateur extends Modele{

    function getUser($login, $password){

        $requete = "SELECT * FROM utilisateur WHERE login LIKE '$login' AND  password LIKE '$password'";
        $ex = $this->getBdd()->query($requete);
        $ex = $ex->fetch();
        return $ex;
    }

    function setUser($pseudo, $login, $password, $mail){
        $requete = "INSERT INTO utilisateur SET pseudo='$pseudo' , login ='$login', password='$password', mail='$mail', codeNiveauSecurite=1, avatar='http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/13/1427481769-dot100.gif' ";
    $ex = $this->getBdd()->query($requete);
    }
}
?>
```

Edit : Thanks guy... I'm so blind...

Comment: LOL for some reason I had same typo just like you, thanks for asked this friend

Answer (score 4):

```
public function inscription($pseudo, $login, $password, $mail);{
                                                              ^
                                                  Get rid of this semi-colon
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `;` after the function definition, so the the method is not getting body of it. Remove the `;` -

```
public function inscription($pseudo, $login, $password, $mail) {
```

Your code -

```
public function inscription($pseudo, $login, $password, $mail);{
```

Comment: Yes thanks you, I just saw it before your answer !

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error missing `;` after **$mail)**

```
 class formInscription {

     private $user;    
     public function __construct(){
         $this->user = new Utilisateur();
     }

     public function inscription($pseudo, $login, $password, $mail){
         session_start();
         $row = $this->user->setUser($pseudo, $login, $password, $mail);
         header ("Location:  /SITEBOUSILLE ");
     }
 }
?>
```